# Generic types with Type.Reflection and Nats

Tags: haskell, generics, types

I have a simple definition for a Nat and a definition for types indexed by Nat's, Natty.

```
data Nat :: * where 
    Zero :: Nat
    Suc  :: Nat -> Nat              deriving(Show, Typeable)

data Natty :: Nat -> * where
    Zy :: Natty Zero
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (Suc n)  deriving Typeable
```

I want to  store and manipulate these Natty's in a generic fashion with the use of the Type.Reflection module.

Storing as a Nat as a type rep works fine.

```
foo :: Nat -> SomeTypeRep
foo x = SomeTypeRep (typeOf x)
```

But storing a Natty as a type rep doesn't work unless extra constraints are added.

```
boo :: Natty n -> SomeTypeRep
boo x = SomeTypeRep (typeOf x)
```

boo produces the following error:

```
No instance for (Typeable n) arising from the use of 'typeOf'
```

**My question is why can Haskell not recognise that n is a nat and should therefore be Typeable?**

Like I said I can fix this issue by adding the constraint of Typeable n to the beginning of boo but when I'm using a function that returns natty in the middle of another function its not that simple.

The following extensions and imports have been used.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-} 
import Type.Reflection
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Typeable n` reflects the fact that GHC will need to pass in a different `Typeable` dictionary into `boo` if it is called with `n` instantiated differently.

There is some cleverness around the interplay of `Typeable` and `DataKinds`. The instances that GHC derives are roughly equivalent to

```
instance Typeable Nat where ...
instance Typeable 'Zero where ...
instance Typeable n => Typeable ('Suc n) where ...
```

The `Typeable n` constraint you are being prompted to add in will not be filled in by the `Typeable Nat` instance (remember `n` has kind `Nat`, not `*`!), but by the latter two constraints.

But, I can hear you saying, why can't GHC figure out by simple induction on those two instances that all `n :: Nat` are `Typeable`? Because `'Zero` and `'Suc` are not the only way of making something of kind `Nat`...

```
ghci> type family Stuck :: k
ghci> :kind Natty Stuck          -- a valid type!
Natty Stuck :: *
```

In other words, GHC can't know at compile time that `n :: Nat` is `Typeable`, you need to pass it a runtime witness of this fact.

Comment: Yes, but with a `Natty`, you actually have all the evidence you need. See my answer.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting! You still end up having to traverse the whole `Natty` at runtime, but the problem is sliced differently. The `App` pattern looks new - I haven't seen it before.

Comment: it came in with `Type.Reflection` in GHC 8.2. The whole `Typeable` situation is much less unsatisfactory now.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the function you want, but not for free.

```
boof :: Natty n -> TypeRep n
boof Zy = typeRep
boof (Sy n) = withTypeable (boof n) typeRep
```

More explicitly (this is basically what happens under the hood in `boof`):

```
goo :: Natty n -> TypeRep n
goo Zy = typeRep @'Zero
goo (Sy n) = App (typeRep @'Suc) (goo n)
```

As `goo` shows, the structure of the `TypeRep` is actually very similar to the structure of the `Natty`. Indeed, you can go the other way too, although you can't convince the pattern checker that it's total:

```
hum :: TypeRep n -> Natty n
hum (App s n)
  | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep s (typeRep @'S) = Sy (hum n)
  | otherwise = error "imp possible"
hum z
  | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep z (typeRep @'Z) = Zy
  | otherwise = error "impposs ible"
```

---

You can wrap up the result as you wish:

```
boo :: Natty n -> SomeTypeRep
boo n = SomeTypeRep (boof n)
```

But it seems likely that you should use something a bit more specific than `SomeTypeRep`. The `Typeable` internals actually use this:

```
data SomeKindedTypeRep k where
  SomeKindedTypeRep :: forall (x :: k). Typeable x => SomeKindedTypeRep k
```

You can define that and use `SomeKindedTypeRep Nat`, or define a specialized version just for `Nat`. That way you don't lose track of the kind (known at compile time) just because you're intentionally forgetting the type.